# Отсутствует иконка почты в панели управления Windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows, email, hyper-v

В общем отсутствует иконка почты в панели управления Windows 2012 R2

Comment: http://s019.radikal.ru/i614/1605/54/ae31c2863071.jpg в упор не вижу как переключиться на 32битную ,  а команда c:\Windows\SysWOW64\control.exe mlcfg32.cpl не работает

Answer (score 1):

Я надеюсь эта [статья](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2008/04/28/where-is-outlook-mail-setup-in-control-panel/) вам поможет

Вы также можете непосредственно открыть Настройку почты , выполнив `“c:\Windows\SysWOW64\control.exe mlcfg32.cpl”`

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/79934)

Comment: Спасибо, исправил